# Updating SQL Server Table from a jTable

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a jTable in my Java application. which is directly filled from an SQL Server table (No Join) The user has the ability to add/delete/update rows. if the user press on the save button all the performed changes on the jTable should be committed on the database.

What is the best approach to implement such user operation?  (deleting and inserting back is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

You can queue your statements (ie: DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT, etc.) into a list based on the actions performed on the local `JTable`. Once the save button is pressed, you can iterate through each query statement in the list and commit the changes to your SQL Server:

```
List<String> listOfStatements = new ArrayList<String>();

Connection connection = new SQLServerDataSource().getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

for(String query : listOfStatements) {
    statement.executeUpdate(query);
}

connection.commit();
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
connection.close();
```

You should make sure that not more than one user is trying to change the database with this method or you may run into problems.

Also, you should use `PreparedStatements` if SQL injection is of concern to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually this is exactly what am currently doing. I wanted a more generic approach since I have lots of tables any idea how to make this code reusable.

Comment: @user1912404 You'll have to tell us more about your implementation in order to narrow the scope on how to make it more re-usable.

Comment: Check the above image the table in the action tab below needs to be synced with the sql server table on save(a button in the above toolbox). the button in buttom right corened add/delete rows.

Comment: @user1912404 Can you show some code that illustrates why you are having issues re-using this approach?